# filter grayscale not working properly on IOS

Tags: ios, css, filter, webview, safari

I have an app that uses a UIWebView to show content and some interaction with the page. Everything has been working properly but now, the images with the css property webkit-filter Grayscale are totally broken, after removing the filter works.

the code is simple, just images with webkit-filter and my iOS app instantiates a UIWebView, nothing more.

I do know that the UIWebView is deprecated but still, seems that the property should work, **or not?**

I tested on IOS 12.1.1 and IOS 11 and still happens.